# Uncaught Error: Secure random number generation is not supported by this browser. Use Chrome, Firefox or Internet Explorer 11

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, simple-peer

I have been learning how to use the simple-peer module to implement WebRTC protocal in a call app, using React , Vite I am having this problem,this warning:

```
simple-peer.js?v=76ad0f10:2833 Module "util" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "util.inspect" in client code. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.
```

as well as this error:
`Uncaught Error: Secure random number generation is not supported by this browser. Use Chrome, Firefox or Internet Explorer 11`

Perticularly when I try to run this line:

```
const peer= new Peer({initiator:false,trickle:false,stream:stream})
```

The whole function:

```
function acceptCall() {
    setCallAccepted(true)
    const peer= new Peer({initiator:false,trickle:false,stream:stream})
    peer.on('signal',data=>{
      // socket.emit('acceptCall',{signal:data,to:caller})
      console.log("Accepting call: signal for the caller",{signal:data})
    })

    peer.on('stream',stream=>{
      partnerVideo.current.srcObject=stream
    })

    //Setting callers signal
    peer.signal(callerSignal)
  }
```

Iv tried updating chrome and using IE11,

Answer (score 0):

Seems the error is for vite, using npx to create the react app seems to work:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```